# How to scrape from new window in current instance of Firefox/Mozilla?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can open a new tab in Firefox/Mozilla, scrape the contents, and write a lot of text to a file, like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request
import webbrowser
url = 'https://console.cloud.google.com/'
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)

r=requests.get(url)
data = r.text

print(data)

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

file = open('C:\\path_here\\test.txt', 'w')
file.write(data)
file.close()
```

The problem is that I'm getting only a fraction of the text, from the web site, into the text file.  How can I dump ALL text from the site to the file?  Some of the content must be dynamically generated, I guess, otherwise everything would be dumped to the text file.  I can tell there is a JavaScript component in the site, but I'm not sure how to exploit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://console.cloud.google.com/')
browser.page_source
```